# Developed JAVA2Wsdl Application using APAche CXF. Need help in adding Security to Soap service

Tags: apache, soap, oauth, cxf

Developed the SOAP Service with APache CXF in Spring Java2WSDL - Bottom-up approach/Code first approach.

I wanna to Secure the SOAP service using APache CXF. or Spring OAuth.

I had come-accross blogs which were implemented wsdl2java.I was really messed up and fed-up with it.

Im new to this Apache CXF stack. So Explanation in brief are most supportive.

Comment: what you had done so far, some code snippets will help somebody to understand you problem.

Comment: I have done with implementing SOAP service by referring the link http://www.benchresources.net/apache-cxf-jax-ws-soap-based-web-service-using-bottom-up-approach/#comment-7922. I want to implement security for the bottom-up approach in soap.